# Chrome will not load a web page with an <embed> element

Tags: google-chrome, audio, vlc-media-player, browser-plugin

I have been trying to get a simple sound web page going:

Sound.html

```
<script>
function PlaySound ()
{
var 
    sounder = document.getElementById ("ToneA") ;

sounder.Play () ;
}

</script>

<embed id="ToneA" height="1" width="1" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/311035/ToneA.mp3" autostart="false" enablejavascript="true"//>
<button onclick="PlaySound () ;">Play</button>
```

The test web page is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/311035/Sound.html).  It plays in IE, but not in Firefox or Chrome.

My problem:  Chrome reports "Could not load VLC Plugin".  It seems to be a known problem that the VLC community don't necessarily feel like fixing at the moment, and is a result of Google choosing not to allow some certain kind of plugin.  If I disable the plugin I no longer get the message but nothing happens when I click the button.  Looking at the console in a debug window I see

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Sound.html:7
PlaySound Sound.html:7
onclick
```

which suggests Chrome could not find anything else to handle the sound file.  How to I tell Chrome to use (e.g.) Windows Media Player?

*** UPDATE ***

This is apparently because the VLC plugin is a [NPAPI plugin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) and Chrome no longer supports these.  I have uninstalled VLC and this has removed the error on loading the webpage with an embedded sound element, but it still doesn't invoke WMP instead.

Comment: Are you wanting to switch to WMP on your machine (on topic here), or have the webpage itself do it for the user? (would be for Stack Overflow)

Comment: Thanks @random. I'm wanting to come up with a "proof of concept" web page that will work with Joe Average's computer and browser, which it does for IE.  My problem is that I can't make Chrome on my PC use whatever IE is using (presumably WMP).  This may be because I had the VLC plug-in installed.